# Hardware compatibility with Hashcat in Windows 10 (64-bit)

Tags: password-cracking, hashcat

This question is not a security question but about a security tool.

Why am I unable to leverage my decent hardware (I think) with hashcat?

This is what I see when I run hashcat in Win 10 (64-bit).

```
C:\Users\USER\Downloads\hashcat-4.0.1>hashcat64.exe -m 1700 -o cracked.txt sha512.txt -a 3 ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
hashcat (v4.0.1) starting...

* Device #1: Intel's OpenCL runtime (GPU only) is currently broken.
             We are waiting for updated OpenCL drivers from Intel.
             You can use --force to override, but do not report related errors.
* Device #4: Not a native Intel OpenCL runtime. Expect massive speed loss.
             You can use --force to override, but do not report related errors.
ADL_Overdrive_Caps(): -8

ADL_Overdrive_Caps(): -8

OpenCL Platform #1: Intel(R) Corporation
========================================
* Device #1: Intel(R) HD Graphics 620, skipped.
* Device #2: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz, skipped.

OpenCL Platform #2: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
================================================
* Device #3: Hainan, 1523/2048 MB allocatable, 5MCU
* Device #4: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz, skipped.

Hashes: 1 digests; 1 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 16 bits, 65536 entries, 0x0000ffff mask, 262144 bytes, 5/13 rotates

Applicable optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Early-Skip
* Not-Salted
* Not-Iterated
* Single-Hash
* Single-Salt
* Brute-Force
* Raw-Hash
* Uses-64-Bit

Password length minimum: 0
Password length maximum: 256

ATTENTION! Pure (unoptimized) OpenCL kernels selected.
This enables cracking passwords and salts > length 32 but for the price of drastical reduced performance.
If you want to switch to optimized OpenCL kernels, append -O to your commandline.

Watchdog: Temperature abort trigger set to 90c
Watchdog: Temperature retain trigger set to 75c

Cracking performance lower than expected?

* Append -O to the commandline.
  This lowers the maximum supported password- and salt-length (typically down to 32).

* Append -w 3 to the commandline.
  This can cause your screen to lag.

* Update your OpenCL runtime / driver the right way:
  https://hashcat.net/faq/wrongdriver

* Create more work items to make use of your parallelization power:
  https://hashcat.net/faq/morework

[s]tatus [p]ause [r]esume [b]ypass [c]heckpoint [q]uit =>

Session..........: hashcat
Status...........: Running
Hash.Type........: SHA-512
Hash.Target......: 88be1866a370d4c538f8fcf5a27d94a681a4e16b43ccf1a2db3...08e862
Time.Started.....: Sat Feb 10 09:27:15 2018 (45 secs)
Time.Estimated...: Sat Feb 10 10:46:11 2018 (1 hour, 18 mins)
Guess.Mask.......: ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d [10]
Guess.Queue......: 1/1 (100.00%)
Speed.Dev.#3.....:  2109.1 kH/s (7.58ms)
Recovered........: 0/1 (0.00%) Digests, 0/1 (0.00%) Salts
Progress.........: 96153600/10000000000 (0.96%)
Rejected.........: 0/96153600 (0.00%)
Restore.Point....: 96000/10000000 (0.96%)
Candidates.#3....: 4124563999 -> 6207615789
HWMon.Dev.#3.....: Temp: 35c Fan:  0% Util: 88% Core:1030MHz Mem:1000MHz Bus:4

[s]tatus [p]ause [r]esume [b]ypass [c]heckpoint [q]uit =>
```

It is clear from above output that everything is not happening in right way.
Then I visited hashcat page and checked the GPU driver requirements and visited:
[AMD Page](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-Software-Crimson-Edition-15.12.aspx)
and
[Intel Page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers)

Then I downloaded and installed AMD Radeon software adrenaline edition but unable to figure out what to download on the Intel page.

Which software should I download in order to use hashcat effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a lot of great news for you, but I do have a couple of pointers.

On the Intel side, as noted in the output, the Intel OpenCL drivers have a known problem with hashcat that must be resolved by Intel. There's not a lot you can do about that part.

On the AMD side, I think that the device that's actually active in your test run - the AMD Hainan - is a Radeon 8800 or similar? If so, it's pretty old, and probably not likely to perform very well. You'd be better off renting an AWS GPU instance.

You might also try `-d 4` to explicitly try the AMD driver for your CPU to see how it performs. It might actually be faster than your AMD GPU.

Once you've got your platform established, adding a couple of options should help:

- `-O` (use optimized kernels, since your target mask is short)
- `-w 4` (highest workload factor)

But that's about all you can do with the platform you have. There are no driver changes that are going to significantly help that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks, BTW I am using Amd Radeon 500 and intel hd graphics 620. What if I download opencl drivers? When I attempted to install opencl runtime then I received a warning "you have to uninstall intel hd graphics before installing opencl runtime SDK so I didn't installed it and decided to ask on community, what to do then?

Comment: I didn't installed open CL runtime SDK also because It can broke my system if it was a wrong driver to install.

Comment: To start new, I would follow the instructions at https://hashcat.net/faq/wrongdriver .

Comment: thank you very much, after appending O and -w 4 , the estimated time to crack sha-512 reduced from 1 hour 18 min to just 3 min 14 sec!